# Delete the char type array

Tags: c++, delete-operator

```
char * a = new char[];
a[0]='1';
delete []a;
```

I didn't specify the size of the array, but when I ran it, it gave a debug error. But when I write this code as follow:

```
char * a = new char[1];
a[0]='1';
delete []a;
```

then it will be OK.

Can any body tell me why it will run correctly when I specify a number?

Comment: When allocating memory, you need to specify how much to allocate. I would be kind of surprised if the first didn't give an error or at least a warning when compiling.

Comment: @Joachim: MSVC accepts the syntax without any diagnostic! I'm quite surprised.

Answer (score 3):

`char * a = new char[];`

doesn't allocates any memory. Its not even a valid statement and should result in an error or warning atleast.

`char * a = new char[1];`

does for a single character and that's why you can use and delete it. The new keyword requires the amount of memory to be allocated.

Comment: I think `char * a = new char[];` is not even a valid statement let alone memory allocation possibility

Comment: @another.anon.coward- I agree. Updated.

Comment: Thanks for update! As pointed out in the comments, MSVC accepts it although g++ throws a compile-time error

Answer (score 1):

When using the new keyword you indicate how much memory you want to reserve.

For example, when you say `char *a = new char[1];` you are saying that you need an array that can hold 1 character.

In the first statement that you posted, you are not reserving any memory and that is why your program is crashing.

Answer (score 0):

`char * a = new char[];`

You should tell how much memory to be allocated, which should be done within `[]`

However for delete you don't need to tell the size of the array, the run-time system knows the size of the array pointed by the pointer `a`

`delete []a;`

But don't forget to put `[]` for deleting the an array.